# Tree using nodes with ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, tree

I'm coding a tree and I need to split a string (ex. `"java.lang.String"` → `"java"`, `"lang"`, `"String"`) and make a tree using those.

Below is my node which has an `ArrayList` as it's children:

```
public class PackageNode {
    String value;
    List<PackageNode> children;

    PackageNode(String value) {
        this.value = value;
        children = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public boolean isLeaf() {
        return children.size() == 0;
    }
}
```

Below is my `add` method for the tree:

```
public boolean add(String className) {
    String[] names = className.split("\\.");

    if (names[0].equals("java")) {
        if (root == null) {
            root = new PackageNode(names[0]);
            PackageNode temp = root;

            for (int i = 1; i < names.length; i++) {
                temp.children.add(new PackageNode(names[i]));
                temp = temp.children.get(0);
            }

            return true;
        } else {
            PackageNode temp = root;
            int i,j;

            for (i = 1; i < names.length; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < temp.children.size(); j++) {
                    if (temp.children.get(j).value.equals(names[i])) {
                        temp = temp.children.get(j);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (j == temp.children.size()) {
                    temp.children.add(new PackageNode(names[i]));
                    temp = temp.children.get(j);
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Below is my `contains` method:

```
public boolean contains(String className) {
    String[] names = className.split("\\.");

    if (names[0].equals(root.value)) {
        PackageNode temp = root;

        for (int i = 1; i < names.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < temp.children.size(); j++) {
                if (temp.children.get(j).value.equals(names[i])) {
                    temp = temp.children.get(j);
                    break;
                }

                if (j == temp.children.size()-1)
                    return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is there anything wrong in my code? If so, how should I change it?
2. I need to implement:

   ```
   public int height()
   public int size()
   public Iterator<PackageNode> iterator()
   ```

Can you give me some help/advice??

Comment: 1. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, 2. what did you try ?

Comment: I just wrote some scratch codes over and over but.. i couldn’t really think up any algorithm for this.. and that's why I want some help or advice on those parts.